# PHP template MVC

Tags: php, mvc

For several days I have been learning about MVC, and I do some code but I don't know if that is correct. I will be grateful for some tips to get this code better.

*Here is my github respository*
https://github.com/DanielPeleton/mvc-php

class/db.php

```
<?php
class db{
    public static $host = '';
    public static $user = '';
    public static $pass = '';
    public static $dbName = '';

    private function connect(){
        $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbName);

        return $con;
    }

    public function query($query, $param = array()){
        if(explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT'){
            $stmt = self::connect()->query($query);
            $result = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            return $result; 
        }else{
            $stmt = self::connect()->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

class/route.php

```
<?php
class route{
    public static $routes = array();
    
    public function set($route, $function){
        self::$routes[] = $route;

        if($_GET['page'] == $route){
            $function->__invoke();
        }else{
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
}
```

controllers/indexController.php

```
<?php
class indexController extends db{
    public function getController($index){
        $data = [
            'example' => 'example',
            'example2' => 'example2'
        ];

        indexModel::getModel($index, $data);
    }
}
```

model/IndexModel.php

```
<?php
class indexModel extends db{
    public function getModel($index, $data){
        /*
            do something on data and index etc
        
        */
        indexView::getView($index, $data);
    }
}
```

view/indexView.php

```
<?php
class indexView{
    public function getView($index, $data){
        require_once('./template/' . $index . '.php');
    }
}
```

route.php

```
<?php
    route::set('index.php', function(){
        indexController::getController('index');
    });
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('route.php');

function __autoload($name){
    $directories = array(
            './class/',
            './controllers/',
            './model/',
            './view/'
    );
    foreach($directories as $dir){
        if(file_exists($dir.$name.'.php')){
            require_once($dir.$name.'.php');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What `$param = array() ` in the db::query() for?

Comment: oh i thought that will be received parameters but i think i should edit that to send prepared statements to db, and delete query() function

Comment: `template MVC`/`do something` sounds [hypothetical code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I mean, it's `db.php` and `route.php`, that's how it actually would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, great that you're learning about the MVC design pattern. It can greatly aid you in improving your code readability and maintainability. That being said, there are ways to further improve this. Such as using a backend framework like [Symfony](https://symfony.com/). It takes care of a lot of structuring, configuration and security related stuff so the programmer doesn't have to think about it anymore.

But you're not using Symfony right now so I will make some remarks on what you did here:

db.php: Don't put db credentials hardcoded in your source files. This makes it harder to change when running the application in production. It's also not the best idea security wise. You don't want to have any credentials in your version control since this gives everyone who has access to the repo full access to the whole production application. Also think about input sanitization: make sure your users can't write malicious queries that are executed on your database. [More about sanitization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/how-can-i-sanitize-user-input-with-php).

Your other classes don't have a lot of functionality so there's less to say about that but some other stuff I noticed was:

- Use CamelCase for classnames, this is a convention most people use and therefore helps other programmers understand your code.
- Some foldernames are both plural and singular, make them either all singular or all plural. This gives a bit more structure.

Comment: hello, what you mean here "db.php: Don't put db credentials hardcoded in your source files. This makes it harder to change when running the application in production."
you mean it should get public/private $host? or other way?

thanks for your post and help :D

Comment: Interestingly, that in the linked post it says "Do not try to prevent SQL injection by sanitizing input data".

Comment: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#:~:text=Class%20names%20MUST,%20StudlyCaps.